# Sending a binary file with RestTemplate, the cURL's --data-binary way

Tags: spring, spring-boot, curl, resttemplate, twilio-api

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of the following cURL command in Spring, to call an API (Twilio) to upload a media :

```
curl --header 'Authorization: Basic <VALID_BASIC_AUTH_TOKEN>' --data-binary "@test.png" https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/<ACCOUNT_ID>/Media -v
```

This request works perfectly, and the headers generated are :

```
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic <VALID_BASIC_AUTH_TOKEN>
> Content-Length: 385884
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

My code in java is :

```
@Repository
public class TwilioMediaRepository {

    private RestTemplate client;

    @Value("${twilio.chat.sid}")
    private String chatSid;

    @Value("${twilio.media.api.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;

    @Value("${twilio.all.accountsid}")
    private String accountSid;

    @Value("${twilio.all.authtoken}")
    private String accountSecret;

    @Autowired
    public TwilioMediaRepository(RestTemplate client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Media postMedia(byte[] file) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        client.getInterceptors().add(new RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor());
        client.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(accountSid, accountSecret));

        HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>(file, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Media> media = this.client.postForEntity(generateUrl(), entity, Media.class);
        return media.getBody();
    }

    private String generateUrl() {
        return String.format(endpoint, chatSid);
    }
}
```

The log of the request show that the headers are exactly the same as the cURL request :

```
URI         : https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/<ACCOUNT_ID>/Media
Method      : POST
Headers     : {Accept=[*/*], Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded], Content-Length=[385884], Authorization=[Basic <VALID_BASIC_AUTH_TOKEN>]}
Request body: <bunch of unreadable bytes>
```

But the log of the response shows that my request is not valid for Twilio :

```
Status code  : 400
Status text  : Bad Request
Headers      : {Content-Type=[text/html], Date=[Wed, 08 Aug 2018 15:32:50 GMT], Server=[nginx], X-Shenanigans=[none], Content-Length=[166], Connection=[keep-alive]}
Response body: <html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How are we supposed to send a binary file to comply with the `--data-binary` property of cURL in Spring ? 
I tried to send `HttpEntity<ByteArrayResource>`, `HttpEntity<byte[]>`, `HttpEntity<FileSystemResource>`, `HttpEntity<ClassPathResource>` but without any success. 
Note : This API doesn't support multipart file upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. Contrarily to what the cURL log show, the API I use doesn't want a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type.

Using the file content-type solve the issue (in my case `image/png`)